# ng-model dentro de um ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Testei várias respostas que encontrei aqui, mas nada resolveu.

Cada `dataSample.name` gera uma linha, com um `SELECT` com outras opções:

Exemplo:

```
dataSample

exame sangue  -------  select -> tipo_de_tubo 1 / tipo_de_tubo_2 / tipo_de_tubo3

exame urina  -------  select -> tipo_de_tubo 1 / tipo_de_tubo_2 / tipo_de_tubo3
```

O que acontece é que, quando eu seleciono o tipo de tubo de qualquer um dos exames, ele se repete pra todos os outros Selects.

```
  <div layout="column" class="mt-20">
    <div layout-gt-xs="row" class="data-row" ng-repeat="dataSample in BioBanco.content.data_sample" ng-model="BioBanco.data">
        <div flex-gt-xs>
          <md-checkbox >
              @{{dataSample.name}}
          </md-checkbox>
        </div>
        
        <div layout-gt-xs>
          <ng-md-icon  icon="opacity"  class="@{{dataSample.slug}}-1"   ng-click="BioBanco.tube(dataSample.slug, 1)" size="24"></ng-md-icon>
          <ng-md-icon  icon="opacity"  class="@{{dataSample.slug}}-2"   ng-click="BioBanco.tube(dataSample.slug, 2)" size="24"></ng-md-icon>
          <ng-md-icon  icon="opacity"  class="@{{dataSample.slug}}-3"   ng-click="BioBanco.tube(dataSample.slug, 3)" size="24"></ng-md-icon>
          <ng-md-icon  icon="opacity"  class="@{{dataSample.slug}}-4"   ng-click="BioBanco.tube(dataSample.slug, 4)" size="24"></ng-md-icon>
          <md-input-container  flex-gt-xs   class="component-render tube-type ">
          <md-tooltip md-direction="top" >Informar Quantidade e Tipo de Tubo</md-tooltip>
            <md-select ng-model="Biobanco.data.tube" aria-label="sexo do paciente"> 
              <md-option value="Citrato">                Citrato</md-option>
              <md-option value="EDTA">                   EDTA</md-option>
              <md-option value="Fluoreto de Sódio">      Fluoreto de Sódio</md-option>
              <md-option value="Heparina">               Heparina</md-option>
              <md-option value="Seco com Gel Reparador"> Seco com Gel Reparador</md-option>
              <md-option value="Sem Conservante">        Sem Conservante</md-option>
              <md-option value="RNA-Later">              RNA-Later</md-option>
              <md-option value="RNA/DNA Reag Estab">     RNA/DNA Reagente Estabilizante</md-option>
              <md-option value="Outros tubos">           Outros</md-option>
            </md-select>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>

        <div layout-gt-xs="row" > 
          <md-input-container  flex-gt-xs class="tube-type after">
          <span class="md-title label">Obs.:</span>
            <input  aria-label="observação" type="text"> 
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: você está usando  a msm ng-model="Biobanco.data.tube" para todos os dentro do repeat isso fará com que que o valor seja sempre o msm para todos é como se vc estivesse duplicando o elemento e não criando  novos. tente mudar o valor dele. para ng-model="Biobanco.data.tube1 ng-model="Biobanco.data.tube2 etc

Comment: Isso não funciona, a não ser que eu colocasse um ng-model dinâmico que fica Biobanco.data.tube.slug, mas não encontrei uma forma de fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi criando o obejto no controller:

```
 this.tubeType   = [
            {name:'Citrato',                        slug: "citrato"},
            {name:'EDTA',                           slug: "edta"},
            {name:'Heparina',                       slug: "heparina"},
            {name:'Seco com Gel Reparador',         slug: "seco-gel-com-reparador"},
            {name:'Sem Conservante',                slug: "sem-conservante"},
            {name:'RNA-Later',                      slug: "rna-later"},
            {name:'RNA/DNA Reagente Estabilizante', slug: "rna-dna-reagente-estabilizante"},
            {name:'Outros',                         slug: "outros"},
          ];


   this.typeSample = {
          buffy_coat:         {status:false, quant: 0, obs: null},
          tecido_nao_tumoral: {status:false, quant: 0, obs: null},
          tecido_normal:      {status:false, quant: 0, obs: null},
          tecido_tumoral:     {status:false, quant: 0, obs: null},
          paaf:               {status:false, quant: 0, obs: null},
          plasma:             {status:false, quant: 0, obs: null},
          soro:               {status:false, quant: 0, obs: null}
        };
```

e no md-select

```
  <md-select   ng-model="BioBanco.typeLiquidSample[liquidSample.slug].set" aria-label="tipo de tubo"> 
    <md-option ng-repeat="tubeType in BioBanco.tubeType" value="@{{tubeType.name}}">
       @{{tubeType.name}} 
    </md-option>                 
</md-select>
```